# How to draw and animate with SurfaceView with delay

Tags: android, multithreading, handler

I'm trying to build a simple Simon Says game. I have 3 randomly placed bitmaps that will change their animation from sleeping to waking up to sleeping and I call this the light up sequence so when app starts, each bitmap will go from sleeping smiley face bitmap->wake up smiley face bitmap-->sleeping face bitmap and there is delay of 1000ms between each transition of smiley faces for each of the 3 bitmaps randomly placed on screen. I get a black screen and I check Android Monitor and it says "sending message to a Handler on a dead thread".
I named my bitmaps that light up a g. dot or good dot. The update method updates the state of the bitmap's image as sleep bitmap or awake bitmap to draw per
bitmap on screen. I'm currently using 3 randomly placed bitmaps. Please help, appreciate it. I didn't include my GoodDot class which is just a class that assigns the default sleep bitmap smiley face and has a method to check that 2 bitmaps don't land on same location on screen and of course tracks a bitmap's location on screen so (x,y) coordinate. Please help, appreciate it.

So part 1 of game is when a new level starts or when app is opened (I'll worry about saving state later) then a random positioned and randomly assigned sequence of the 3 bitmaps will light up

part 2: just to run the while loop at bottom of the run method and basically i'll add detecting touch for player to press on the bitmaps in correct sequence to win a level.

Here is the MainActivity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private Handler myHandler;
Canvas canvas;
Paint paint;
GameView gameView;
Bitmap restBitmap;
Bitmap awakeBitmap;
final int NUM_GOOD_DOTS = 3;
static int curPos = 0;//cur g. dot doing its light up sequence
GoodDot goodDotList[];

int screenWidth;
int screenHeight;
//The size in pixels of a place on the game board
int blockSize;
int numBlocksWide;
int numBlocksHigh;

static boolean isFirstTimeSettingUpGoodDotPosns = false;
static boolean isLightUpSequenceFinishedForCurLevel = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    gameView = new GameView(this);
    canvas = new Canvas( );
    paint = new Paint ( );
    myHandler = new Handler();
    configureDisplay();
    setContentView(gameView);

}//END METHOD: onCreate

class GameView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, Runnable {

    private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;//this lets us access the canvas but still need to use Canvas class
    private Thread myThread;

    public GameView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        myThread = new Thread();
        surfaceHolder = getHolder();
        surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        myThread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder,
                               int format, int width, int height) {
        // What do I enter here???
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        boolean retry = true;
        while (retry) {
            try {
                myThread.join();
                retry = false;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        isLightUpSequenceFinishedForCurLevel = false;
    }

    protected void drawSomething ( ) {
        Log.i ("curPos so far:", "" + curPos );

        if (surfaceHolder.getSurface().isValid() ) {
            canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();

            if (isFirstTimeSettingUpGoodDotPosns == false) {

                //assign random posns to bitmaps
                //  as they are NOT on same spot on screen!
                Random r = new Random();
                for (int i = 0; i < NUM_GOOD_DOTS; i++) {
                    goodDotList[i] = new GoodDot(1, 1, restBitmap);
                    goodDotList[i].setGoodDotX((r.nextInt(3) + 1) * blockSize);
                    goodDotList[i].setGoodDotY((r.nextInt(3) + 1) * blockSize);
                }

                //this method ensures no bitmaps land on same position 
                //   on screen
                gameView.assignProperPosnForGoodDots();

                isFirstTimeSettingUpGoodDotPosns = true;
            }

            canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);//the background
            paint.setColor(Color.argb(255, 255, 255, 255));
            paint.setStrokeWidth(3);

            // for loop to draw all g. dots
            for (int i = 0; i < NUM_GOOD_DOTS; i++) {

                canvas.drawBitmap(goodDotList[i].getBitmap(),
                        goodDotList[i].getGoodDotX(), goodDotList[i].getGoodDotY(), paint);
            }

            //this method called is only for testing
            drawGrid(canvas);
            surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
    }//END IF BLOCK: For valid surfaceHolder
 }//END METHOD: drawSomething

    //this method is only for testing to see the grid that each bitmap is inside a block
    private void drawGrid ( Canvas canvas ) {

        //var to draw horizontal line part of grid
        float rowStartX = 0; float rowStartY = 0;
        float rowEndX = screenWidth;  float rowEndY = 0;

        //var to draw vertical line part of grid
        int colStartX = 0; int colStartY = 0;
        int colEndX = 0;  int colEndY = screenHeight;

        // Log.d("NUM BLOCKS HIGH", "Value:" + numBlocksHigh );

        //draw the horizontal lines
        for ( int i  = 0; i < numBlocksHigh; i++ ) {
            canvas.drawLine ( rowStartX, rowStartY, rowEndX, rowEndY , paint );
            rowStartY += blockSize;
            rowEndY += blockSize;
        }

        //draw the vertical lines
        for ( int i  = 0; i < numBlocksWide; i++ ) {
            canvas.drawLine ( colStartX, colStartY, colEndX, colEndY , paint );
            colStartX += blockSize;
            colEndX += blockSize;
        }
    }//END METHOD: drawGrid

    //Each g. dot goes thru 3 states: rest, light up/awake, rest
    public void update() {

        switch ( goodDotList [ curPos ].getGoodDotState() ) {
            case 1:
                goodDotList[ curPos ].setBitmap( restBitmap );
                break;
            case 2:
                goodDotList[ curPos ].setBitmap( awakeBitmap );
                break;
            case 3:
                goodDotList[ curPos ].setBitmap( restBitmap );
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        //Go to next g. dot once 3 states finished for a given g. dot
        if ( goodDotList [ curPos ].getGoodDotState() > 3 ) {
            curPos++;
        }
        else {
            goodDotList [ curPos ].setGoodDotState(
                    goodDotList [ curPos ].getGoodDotState() + 1 );
        }
    }//END METHOD: update

    //this method makes sure no GOOD DOTS land on same spot
    public void assignProperPosnForGoodDots ( ) {

        int curGdotPos = 0;
        Random rand = new Random ();
        boolean isHitFound = false;

        while ( curGdotPos < NUM_GOOD_DOTS ) {

            for (int j  = curGdotPos + 1; j < NUM_GOOD_DOTS; j++ ) {

                if ( goodDotList [ curGdotPos ].checkForHit( NUM_GOOD_DOTS, goodDotList [ j ] ) ) {
                    goodDotList[curGdotPos].setGoodDotX( (rand.nextInt(3) + 1) * blockSize  )  ;
                    goodDotList[curGdotPos].setGoodDotY( ( rand.nextInt(3) + 1) * blockSize  );
                    isHitFound = true;
                    break;
                }
            }//END INNER FOR LOOP

            if ( isHitFound ) {
                curGdotPos = 0;
                isHitFound = false;//reset for next round
            }
            else
                curGdotPos++;
        }//END WHILE LOOP
    }//END METHOD: assignProperPosnForGoodDots

    @Override
    public void run() {

        if (curPos < NUM_GOOD_DOTS) {
            Log.i("hi", "hi, more g. dots to light up!");
            gameView.update();
            gameView.drawSomething();
        }
        if ( curPos < NUM_GOOD_DOTS ) {
            myHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
        else {
            isLightUpSequenceFinishedForCurLevel = true;
        }

        while ( isLightUpSequenceFinishedForCurLevel )
            gameView.drawSomething( );
    }

}//END INNER CLASS: GameView

/**
 * BELOW are Main Activity Life Cycle Call Back methods!
 */
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Log.d("onStop", "Main Activity's onStop called");
    gameView.surfaceDestroyed( gameView.getHolder() );
    this.finish();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.d("onResume", "Main Activity's onResume called");

    gameView = new GameView(this);
    setContentView(gameView);
    gameView.surfaceCreated( gameView.getHolder() );
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.i("onPause", "Main Activity's onPause called");
    gameView.surfaceDestroyed( gameView.getHolder() );
}

public void configureDisplay() {
    //find out the width and height of the screen
    Display display =
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    screenWidth = size.x;
    screenHeight = size.y;

    //Determine the size of each block/place on the game board
    blockSize = screenWidth/10;

    //Determine how many game blocks will fit into the
    //height and width
    //Leave one block for the score at the top
    numBlocksWide = 10;
    numBlocksHigh = ( ( screenHeight ) ) / blockSize;

    //Load and scale bitmaps
    restBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.good_dot_rest_state );
    awakeBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.good_dot_light_up_state );

    //scale the bitmaps to match the block size
    restBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap( restBitmap,
            blockSize  , blockSize , false);
    awakeBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap( awakeBitmap,
            blockSize , blockSize , false);

    goodDotList = new GoodDot[ NUM_GOOD_DOTS ];

  //initialize g. dots w coordinate (0,0)
    for ( int i = 0; i < NUM_GOOD_DOTS; i++ )
        goodDotList [ i ] = new GoodDot( 0, 0, restBitmap );

}//END METHOD: configureDisplay

}//END CLASS: MainActivity
```

Comment: what do you need `myThread` for? it is started but it is doing nothing

Comment: Ok, I thought myThread is used to run the overrided run method because I made my nested GameView class implements Runnable but i'm need of assistance because I wanted to use Handler too for delaying part 1 of game as I explained in Original Post.

Comment: so what problems do you have with `Handler`s?

Comment: I wanted to use Handler for delaying the light up sequence and I just tried moving Handler to be the nested GameView class' instance variable but when I run app, I get black screen and I check Android Monitor and I still get message: "sending message to a Handler on a dead thread".

Comment: start with this: https://pastebin.com/FSKD9arF

Comment: Thanks so much for that. So I see handleMessage can contain the code to run the animation on worker thread. There's just so many ways to use worker threads otherwise I would've completed this game when I did it in JavaScript albeit not efficiently, all this worker thread stuff, handlers... I'm going to play around with your code that I got working first and go from there. Thanks again! And I would've never thought of using Handler.Callback

Comment: Ok, now my bitmaps show up, no more black screen. I tried your code so for now I'm just trying to get light up sequence to work so it just repeats so I mean once all 3 bitmaps are done their light up sequence, it cycles back and repeats sequence but i don't know why it won't show the bitmaps changing from: sleep smiley face bitmap to awake smiley face bitmap back to sleep smiley face bitmap. I also noticed in Android Monitor, I get the message still: "sending message to a Handler on a dead thread". For your code, I don't see that message. Here is my updated src: https://pastebin.com/inVAgwG2

Comment: pastebin says: **Private Paste ID: inVAgwG2
This is a private paste.**

Comment: Sorry, here it is again: https://pastebin.com/inVAgwG2

Comment: looks ok, so whats the stacktrace? did my code work (without any changes)?

Comment: Yes, your code was fine, just a line to check that the surface or holder or whatever it's called is valid first so an if-block around your pastebin code:  if ( holder.getSurface().isValid() ) { //your code that works perfectly } or else i get NullPointerException

Comment: so add your code in little steps and check when it crashes

Comment: Sure, i'll give it another go

Comment: frustrating...app doesn't crash & it draws my bitmaps but issue is i don't see handler delaying each frame for 1sec b/t each bitmap to simulate light up sequence (i want each bitmap go from: rest smiley face bitmap, pause 1sec, change cur bitmap to awake smiley face bitmap, pause 1 sec, change cur bitmap back to sleep/rest smiley face bitmap, pause 1 sec so repeat for each bitmap...it can't be handleMessage, right since that is running stuff on worker thread...like I said app doesn't crash but Android Monitor:"sending message to a Handler on a dead thread", not w your code though...WHY ME...

Comment: any suggestions, Pskink

Comment: i have no idea about ""sending message to a Handler on a dead thread" as there is no background thread here

Comment: I thought the SurfaceView drawing is done on background thread and the handler is like middleman to communicate to main/UI thread so that it doesn't freeze up waiting for the SurfaceView drawings taking place?

Comment: so instead of `myHandler = new Handler(this);` try `myHandler = new Handler(ht.getLooper(), this);` where `ht` is: `HandlerThread ht = new HandlerThread("worker"); ht.start();`

Comment: Ok, I'll try that out but it shouldn't matter...

Comment: Thanks for your help, Pskink! I've solved it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly of me, the reason my bitmaps weren't changing from rest smiley face bitmap to awake smiley face bitmap back to rest smiley face bitmap was because in my bitmap class my setter was redundant as in: public void setBitmap (Bitmap bmp_) {
this.bmp = this.bmp;}...should be: this.bmp = bmp_!